# Accessing a specific tab on a webpage using AppleScript and JavaScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to connect to the second of three tabs on a webpage, using AppleScript and JavaScript.
The code on the page looks like this. (For those of you who care, this is the Zoom recording analytics page.

```
<div class="zm-tabs__nav-scroll">
<div role="tablist" aria-label="Tabs of Recording Analytics" class="zm-tabs__nav is-top" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
<div id="tab-summary" aria-controls="pane-summary" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" class="zm-tabs__item is-top is-active">
<h2 class="tab-h2-item"> Summary </h2></div>
<div id="tab-play" aria-controls="pane-play" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" class="zm-tabs__item is-top">
<h2 class="tab-h2-item"> By View </h2></div>
<div id="tab-download" aria-controls="pane-download" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" class="zm-tabs__item is-top">
<h2 class="tab-h2-item"> By Download 
</h2></div></div></div>
```

This works on the first tab, allowing me to click on the button and download the .csv file.

```
set UUID to "double-encoded string"
set theURL to "https://my-url.zoom.us/recording/analytics?meeting_id="
set theClassName to "zm-button__slot"
set elementnum to 0

to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "Safari" to open location theURL & UUID
    
    delay 1
end tell

clickClassName("zm-button--link", 0)
```

There is, however, a tab named "By View" that has the id of `tab-play`. I want to get to that tab and click the download button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the **URL** of the target webpage available to anyone without a login? If yes what is the actual **URL** of the target webpage?

Comment: The target URL is restricted to people with Zoom licenses from our organization.